# TideSDK support for HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, tidesdk

I'm planning to use TideSDK to port an existing web-application to the desktop. The webapp makes extensive use of the HTML5 canvas and I wanted to ask if someone already has some experience with a TideSDK app that makes use of the HTML5 canvas and if it's generally possible doing something like that? 
 I already compiled a stripped-down version of my webapp with TideSDK to do a test and the canvas didn't seem to work at all. 
 So I assume that either I missed something when setting up the app or the Webkit engine that TideSDK is using still has to be updated? Any hints?

Comment: I'm having the same question. I would like to use some more complex shapes, and I'm looking for either canvas or svg support. Did you found something useful ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answer comes too late, but I am doing exactly this at the moment and I found this question.

Using TideSDK v1.3.1 beta and TideSDK Developer 1.4.2 everything is working for me (in my case it's a javascript game being rendered inside a canvas using only the 2D functionality -- without any webgl). I only had to place an index.html inside the Resources folder of the application, including the necessary scripts (and launching them, of course), and the app worked.

Note 1: I found some minor issues which make me think this webkit is a slightly different version (some errors when trying to do a drawImage with coordinates outside of an image, which seems to work in other webkit versions). If you launch the app from the TideSDK developer you can do right-click inside the window and select 'Show inspector', as in any other browser. You can't do that when launching the app from the executable.

Note 2: Bad news: the framerate drops to less than a half. I went from 60 frames per second to 15~30 in a not very complex game, which makes my experiment unusable.